# Define a mapping $T$ from $ l_{\infty} $ to $ l_1$ such that $ T \in L( l_{\infty}, l_1) $

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am supposed to define a mapping $ T:l_{\infty} \rightarrow  l_1 $ as $T(a_n) = (d_n a_n) $ ,where $ (d_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} $ is a sequence of scalars, and T is linear , continuous,onto and isometry.

I've  tried the following mapping $$ T(a_n) = (\frac{1}{2^n} \frac{a_n}{1+a_n}) . $$
 Even though T in this case is well-defined , continuous and onto , but it is not linear and I cannot show it is an isometry.

Comment: What is $a_n$ for you?

Comment: There is no such $T$ that satisfies the properties you require because $\ell^1$ is separable and $\ell^\infty$ is not.

Comment: @UrbanPENDU Can you spesifically tell me which conditions have to fail ? or  which ones cannot hold together?